# Is possible to add an aggregate field with an expression including other aggregate field?

Tags: delphi

Well, i have a ClientDataSet used to calculate a ticket:

amount: InternalCalc float
price:  InternalCalc float
subtotal: InternalCalc Float price * amount

total: AgreggateField in Expression i have: sum(subtotal)
now is the problem:

I try to add an aggregate field "discount" with expression: total -(total* 0.2) to obtain the amount of a 20% of discount.

I obtain: Bit Index out of range.
Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Is this of any help?  http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=113836

Comment: There is no other way using the componnent? A clientdataset can contain only one aggregate field?